# Made changes to cakephp view files but changes not showing in browser

Tags: php, cakephp

This one is quit puzzling to me. Please help

I baked a cake using root via ssh and everything went well except for the fact that i could not edit the view CTP files in dreamweaver. kept getting "access denied. Permission problem".

Via ssh and the cpanel i was able to change the permission to 755, 777. Got an error when attempted to change permission via dreamweaver

After changing file permission, I still got the error "access denied. permission problem.."

I then change the USER who owns the file using chown via ssh

I was then able to edit the file without error. I viewed the edited file via cpanel and realized that the changes took place. Bravo!

However, when i viewed the page in the browser, no changes were apparent.

I cleared the cache several times. My tmp folder is chmod 777

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/scaffolding.html) perhaps? If so, disable it to see what happens.
Double check if these file names are correct too: Controller, View files and View folder.

Comment: Scaffolding was the issue

Comment: Had the same issue here. Wasted hours on it, thank you for stopping me wasting anymore!